# When I have long text, I have to make text-indent except first line

Tags: css

I have a problem with text-indent.

Here is the image **what I want to make.**

[image]

I don't want to use `<li>`.

I want to make custom list style.

Here is my code.

```css
.dotted-style{
  width: 200px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.dotted-style::before{
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: auto 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p class="dotted-style">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Possimus aliquam non aspernatur reprehenderit, velit, laboriosam harum aut dolorum, quasi a iure maiores. Eos laboriosam exercitationem quasi magni doloribus fuga rerum?
</p>
```

Comment: Would `padding-left: 20px; text-indent: -15px;` declared on `.dotted-style` work for you?

Comment: Also, you have two applicable answers below, with `margin` and `padding` variations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with margin:

**CSS:**

```
.dotted-style {
  width: 200px;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin-left: 15px;/*added*/
}

.dotted-style::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: auto 5px auto -10px;/*modified*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2189/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.dotted-style{
  width: 200px;
  word-break: break-all;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:15px;
}

.dotted-style::before{
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: auto 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's good answer. But I don't want to use `position: absolute`.